# Django - Does not insert null and producing ValueError

Tags: python, django

I am uploading product catalog from `csv` file into below DB model
**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   invoice_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def load_product(relative_path):
    if relative_path is not None:
        with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, relative_path)) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                if row[0] != 'id':
                    _, created = Product.objects.get_or_create(
                        name=row[1],
                        invoice_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(str(row[2]), "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                    )
    else:
        return "Please enter a relative file name from data folder."
```

Here is the sample **csv file** data

```
id,name,invoice_date
,sample book1,26-10-2007
,sample book2,15-10-2010
,sample book3,22-09-2017,
,sample book4,,
,sample book5,,
```

Some of my books `don't have invoice_date` so i want to insert None type (or empty), that's why i made `blank=True, null=True` in `models.py`, but it does not insert null and gives me following error when i execute the method using shell
**error**

```
  File "C:\Python35\lib\_strptime.py", line 510, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\_strptime.py", line 343, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'
```

Comment: before convert string date to date format, you need to check that value is empty or not.

Comment: how can i do that inside `Product.objects.get_or_create`

Comment: before insert record, need to check. If value is not empty than convert to date format, otherwise just add name value.

Comment: I guess you get that error because the function _strptime needs a non-null argument. It has nothing to do with your model

Comment: but that's why we use `models` to check if it is required or not before we
 create into db with django methods such as `get_or_create` right?

Comment: @Srinivas Basically you need to pass `None` instead of an empty string

Comment: do i need to do that for each field because data is from `csv` file and i have many fields with `django date`, `time formats`, don't think we can do this with signals, decorators?